# "Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection"

Tags: r

I'm trying to conduct CFA but suddenly this error appear and now I cannot use r anymore since no metter what data I use it always give me the "Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection".
This is the code that I'm using right now: 
data

```
data <- read.delim("C:/Users/Nyname/Desktop/data.txt")
View(data)
```

## model

```
overall_data <- ' 
f1 =~ item_3 + item_4 + item_12 + item_16
f2 =~ item_1 + item_5 + item_9 + item_14 + item_18
```

## fit

```
overall_datafit <- cfa(overall_data, data=data, meanstructure = TRUE)
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

I'v tried to change the directory, using setwd() and to unistall and install but nothing seems to work. I really hope somebody can help me because I've no idea what to do next and I really need to finish my work.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please [edit] your post and post the *complete* code you're using to turn this into a [MCVE] ? Also, did you double-check whether the file exists at the given location? Did you test your code with different paths (e.g. a relative one, where the data file is in the same directory as your script) ?

Comment: I checked many time and tried many different paths with different data but it simply keep giving me that error. This error appear suddenly for a while I used my data and it worked without problem.

Comment: From [`?cfa`](https://github.com/cran/cfa/blob/master/man/cfa.Rd#L15-L18), it says that the first argument `cfg` *"Contains the configurations. This can be a dataframe or a matrix."*, while it appears that you are passing a string. I don't know `cfa`, but my *guess* is that even though the function does use [`as.data.frame(cfg)`](https://github.com/cran/cfa/blob/master/R/cfa.r#L138), perhaps this is not the correct format? (In the [*Examples*](https://github.com/cran/cfa/blob/master/man/cfa.Rd#L108-L111) section, it builds `configs` which is a matrix, not a string.)

Answer (score 0):

I also came across similar kind of error when I worked on windows, and was not able to resolve what was the problem with my code.

If you are windows below will help, as I finally found out what the problem actually was:

When you name your file `"blabla.txt"` then windows name it `"blabla.txt.txt"`... That's the same with `.CSV` files so windows create a file named `"bla.csv.csv"` if you called it `"bla.csv"`

So, when you create your .txt file, just rename it "data" and open it in R using `data <- read.delim("C:/Users/Nyname/Desktop/data.txt")`

It worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing work, but I'm starting to think that something is wrong with my r studio event though I uninstall and than installed it again. Even analysis I did a week ago now don't work.  When  I run some code they just keep loading or giving me error, but they worked before!
I really don't know what to do and I really need to have these information

Comment: Have you completely removed the old R-studio env?. As sometimes when you only uninstall the old R-studio system files are left and again when you install fresh R-studio, it picks up the old system files and you might face the same problems again.

Comment: I uninstalled it, used cc cleaner and then removed a folder that still was in AppData. I'm going to do it once more hoping that it would help; should I do it in a different way? Thank you for your help

Comment: For windows I generally use a software called `IOBit Uninstaller` which removes all the residuals present anywhere on the system. You can use this, free version is available-soft suggestion

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late for answering this question, but others may also face it.

It is possible that you have loaded another package that masks the function `cfa()` from lavaan (e.g., package "sem" or other packages that require it such as "faoutlier"). If so, you will face this error.

If this is the case, using `lavaan::cfa()` instead of `cfa()` should resolve the problem.